# AVAssetWriter memory allocation skyrockets after movie creation

Tags: swift, instruments, allocation, metal, avassetwriter

I have a routine in my app which captures MTLTextures into a movie via AVAssetWriter.  When I run the app on a device, memory management seems to hold steady, and the movie gets created and written to disk.  However, when I published the app on the App Store (and downloaded it) the app crashes shortly after movie creation, regardless of the movie size.  Running the app through instruments shows tremendous memory allocation happening in the routine that extracts a PixelBuffer from the MTLTextures.  This is where the crash is happening.  The routine in question runs inside a loop for every MTLTexture that I want to record:

```
func AVAssetWriterEncodeFrame(forTexture texture: MTLTexture) {

    while !assetWriterVideoInput!.isReadyForMoreMediaData  {
    } // hang out here until isReadyForMoreMediaData == true

    autoreleasepool(invoking: { () -> () in

      let fps: Int32 = Int32(Constants.movieFPS)

      guard let pixelBufferPool = assetWriterPixelBufferInput!.pixelBufferPool else {
        print("[MovieMakerVC]: Pixel buffer asset writer input did not have a pixel buffer pool available; cannot retrieve frame")
        return
      }

      var maybePixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer? = nil
      let status  = CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(nil, pixelBufferPool, &maybePixelBuffer)
      if status != kCVReturnSuccess {
        print("[MovieMakerVC]: Could not get pixel buffer from asset writer input; dropping frame...")
        return
      }
      guard let pixelBuffer = maybePixelBuffer else { return }
      CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, [])
      let pixelBufferBytes = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer)!

      // Use the bytes per row value from the pixel buffer since its stride may be rounded up to be 16-byte aligned
      let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer)
      let region = MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height)

      texture.getBytes(pixelBufferBytes, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, from: region, mipmapLevel: 0)

      let presentationTime = CMTimeMake(value: Int64(frameIndexForPresentationTime), timescale: fps)

      assetWriterPixelBufferInput!.append(pixelBuffer, withPresentationTime: presentationTime)

      CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, [])

      frameIndexForPresentationTime += frameHoldLength  // set up for next frame

    }) // end of autoreleasepool

  } // end of func AVAssetWriterEncodeFrame(forTexture texture: MTLTexture)
```

[image: allocations crash]

[image: allocations list]

The spike seen in the graph grows uncontrollably AFTER the movie gets written to disk.  The allocations list shows thousands of entries that look like:

@autoreleasepool content. ... 4 KiB AVFoundation. -[AVAssetWriterinput helper]. (as seen on image above)

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong and hopefully how to fix it?

Comment: Can you show us the allocation list, indicating the types of live objects that are consuming the memory, and where they're allocated?

Comment: Thanks @warrenm.  I've added more detail, which I'm hoping will shed some light into the problem. Although I've taken care to do proper memory management, I'm not sure why/where objects are not being released or deallocated

Answer (score 0):

The culprit turned out to be this bit of code:

while !assetWriterVideoInput!.isReadyForMoreMediaData  {
    } // hang out here until isReadyForMoreMediaData == true

It turns out that testing for falsehood of this condition in the AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor object is a really BAD idea.

Instead, wrapping the entirety of that logic bloc as follows is the way to go:

```
var frameIsCaptured: Bool = false

while (assetWriterVideoInput!.isReadyForMoreMediaData && frameIsCaptured == false) {     
    ... // insert all the texture processing logic
    texture.getBytes(pixelBufferBytes, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, from: region, mipmapLevel: 0)
    ... // insert pixelBuffer ingestion logic
    frameIsCaptured = true. // needed so we only process this texture once
}
```

What I was doing before achieved the same thing in the sense that the routine would loop endlessly until `isReadyForMoreMediaData` became true (at which point I would to all the texture work needed to append the pixelBuffer to the movie-in-progress), but the ridiculous overhead created by that empty loop is not something that seemed to be a design flaw to address.  Of course, Instruments pointed to there being an issue in this loop, but it took me a while to see the light.